# Heroku build failing with "Push rejected, failed to compile Python app."

Tags: python, heroku

Anyone else having problems deploying a python app to heroku?

I tried to deploy a previous version of our app that had successfully deployed and I still got this error.

```
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote: -----> Installing python-2.7.16
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing dependencies with Pipenv 2018.5.18…
remote: Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (d06116)…
remote: -----> Installing SQLite3
remote: ! Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote:
remote: ! Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote:
remote: !   Push rejected to nursefly.
remote:
```

Is there any way to get more debug info about why the build is failing?

Comment: This appears to be an [infrastructure problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56677029/heroku-python-app-failing-to-build-when-installing-sqlite3/56677316#comment99936903_56677029)

Comment: Thanks Chris. Looks like my question is a duplicate of that one.